# Java sorted table listener

Tags: java, sorting

I have a table with a row sorter on -> `setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);`  and ListSelectionModel to which i attached the listener. If i sort it (by clicking on the header) .

```
tableProducts=new JTable(table_modelProducts);
tableProducts.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
cellSelectionModelProducts = tableProducts.getSelectionModel();
cellSelectionModelProducts.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
```

The problem is that if sort it and then click on a cell it returns the original value located at that position(the one that was there before table sorting):

```
if(arg0.getValueIsAdjusting()){
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(tableProducts.getModel().getValueAt(tableProducts.getSelectedRow(), 1)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you read java code, getSelectedRow() is on selection model, while getModel() returns data model. Data model and selection model are 2 different models and that's why you can't get correct index back.

The right solution is to call JTable.getRowSorter().convertRowIndexToModel() to get data model index. The sorter is the one that shuffles your underlying data model into a view model. Logically thinking, it must be the one maintaining the mapping between 2 models. So your code should be

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf(tableProducts.getModel()
  .getValueAt(tableProducts.getRowSorter().convertRowIndexToModel(
  tableProducts.getSelectedRow()), 1)));
```

Take JTable example from Java Tutorial as a base, see the line with **System.out.println("Right Value = ")** how to call the above method, full code is here. It is executable, you can test it by starting the application, click last name column header and then click each last name, observe console output.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

/*
 * SimpleTableDemo.java requires no other files.
 */

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class SimpleTableDemo extends JPanel {
    private boolean DEBUG = false;

    public SimpleTableDemo() {
        super(new GridLayout(1,0));

        String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
                                "Last Name",
                                "Sport",
                                "# of Years",
                                "Vegetarian"};

        Object[][] data = {
        {"Kathy", "Smith",
         "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
        {"John", "Doe",
         "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
        {"Sue", "Black",
         "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
        {"Jane", "White",
         "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
        {"Joe", "Brown",
         "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
        };

        final JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                if(e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                    System.out.println("Wrong Value = " + String.valueOf(table.getModel().getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 1)));
                    System.out.println("Right Value = " + String.valueOf(table.getModel().getValueAt(table.getRowSorter().convertRowIndexToModel(table.getSelectedRow()), 1)));
                }
            }

        });
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        if (DEBUG) {
            table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    printDebugData(table);
                }
            });
        }

        //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    private void printDebugData(JTable table) {
        int numRows = table.getRowCount();
        int numCols = table.getColumnCount();
        javax.swing.table.TableModel model = table.getModel();

        System.out.println("Value of data: ");
        for (int i=0; i < numRows; i++) {
            System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
            for (int j=0; j < numCols; j++) {
                System.out.print("  " + model.getValueAt(i, j));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------");
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleTableDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        SimpleTableDemo newContentPane = new SimpleTableDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated my answer with sample code. See the line that prints Right Value.